# Document Viewer for Web application

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a web application with Devexpress Aspxgridview containing the list of documents. These documents are scanned copies or word documents (TIF, DOC) are saved on different server .
 Can you help me with a way to view these documents on row click of the gridview ( something like a document viewer, where we can have options to Zoom the doucments, rotate and print)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is for asp.net, you can have a look at "Doconut" for online viewing of various document formats from an asp.net 4.0 application. It is a paid library available for .net 4.0 only.